Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'SDWebImageOperation.h' file not found al compilar un proyecto Flutter
Estoy desarrollando una aplicación móvil con Flutter y tengo configurado un proyecto iOS. Uso CocoaPods para gestionar las dependencias en la carpeta ios. Sin embargo, al compilar el proyecto en Xcode, obtengo el siguiente error:
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'SDWebImageOperation.h' file not found
/Users/xxxxxx/Projects/App/AppTest/ios/Pods/SDWebImage/SDWebImage/Core/SDWebImageManager.h:9:8

Pasos que he seguido:

Ejecuté flutter pub get para instalar las dependencias de Flutter.
Navegué a la carpeta ios y ejecuté pod install.
Intenté limpiar y reconstruir el proyecto con los comandos:

flutter clean
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
pod deintegrate
pod install
flutter pub get
flutter run

Verifiqué que el archivo Podfile tiene configurada la versión mínima de iOS (platform :ios, '13.0').
A pesar de estos pasos, el error persiste al compilar. Agradecería cualquier ayuda para resolver este problema y poder continuar con el desarrollo de la aplicación.

Claro.
Este problema regularmente se da al clonar repositorios pero pueden haber otros casos donde ocurra. En mi caso eliminando

.flutter-plugins
.flutter-plugins-dependencies
pubspec.lock

Y generar de nuevo estos archivos ya podrás compilar sin problema.

No he clonado el proyecto. Me di cuenta de que este problema ocurre con el paquete file_picker que estoy utilizando. Es posible que se deba a las versiones de CocoaPods, Xcode u otras configuraciones. Cuando encuentre la solución, la compartiré.
